# Getting Inconsistent result while using UNION ALL with CTEs in Impala

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, impala, union-all

Has anyone ever faced data consistency issue while using UNION ALL with CTEs in impala.

I have two CTEs T1 and T2 . T1 has 264 distinct rows and T2 has 35 distinct rows.
T1 UNION ALL T2 is giving me just 56 rows but logically it should be returning 299 rows.
It looks like an impala bug to me. 
I could not able to find any info regarding this except an old thread about impala issue which got closed long back. 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-2088

Comment: In order to give us a chance to help, you should really provide a Minimal-Reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or at least query profile in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed an impala bug.
It has been identified as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-7957.
It got fixed in latest impala version.